# Стоит ли объединять секции в контроллер?

Tags: c#, wpf, архитектура

### Теория приложения

У меня есть приложение "тестировщик". В любом тестировании есть минимум 3 секции:

1. Секция с кнопкой начать тестирование (возможно ещё с настройками тестирования: время на прохождение, кол-во билетов - лично **у меня так**);
2. Секция с самими билетами и кнопка переключения на следующий билет. Также тут выводится оставшееся время(если оно было установлено), прогресс - сколько из скольки билетов пройдено;
3. И наконец секция с выводом результатов тестирования.

Дабы **контролировать** введённые данные в первой секции, выводить новые билеты по нажатию на кнопку "**Следующий билет**", также показывать прогресс и т.п. по 2 пункту списка и выводить результаты теста **нужно создать** некий `class TestingController`.

### Код приложения

В нём такого рода код **(я не писал ещё кучу *нужных* вспомогательных полей, свойств и методов, которые нужны для каждой секции)**:

```
class TestingController
{
    /// ПЕРВАЯ СЕКЦИЯ (НАСТРОЙКА И НАЧАЛО ТЕСТИРОВАНИЯ)

    // Время тестирования
    DateTime TestingTime { get; set; } 
    // Количество билетов
    int TicketsAmount { get; set; }
    // Этот метод будет вызываться при нажатии на кнопку "Начать тестирование"
    void GetStarted()
    {
        //// Выводим вторую секцию
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////        

    /// ВТОРАЯ СЕКЦИЯ (БИЛЕТЫ)

    // Вывод нового билета
    void GetNextTicket()
    {
        //// код замены значений у UIElement'ов
    }
    // Выводим  "пройдено_билетов/осталось"
    void OutputTestingProgress()
    {
        //// код
    }
    // Выводим оставшееся время на прохождение теста каждую секунду с помощью класса Timer
    void OutputTimeLeft()
    {
        //// код
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /// ТРЕТЬЯ СЕКЦИЯ (РЕЗУЛЬТАТЫ)
    void GetResults()
    {
        // выводим третью секцию
    }
}
```

### Вопрос

Стоит ли так делать: объединять весь функционал 3-х секций приложения в один класс_контроллер? Или же всё таки более **правильным** будет *разделить этот класс на 3 таких же контроллера для каждой секции*, в каждом из которых будут хранится их свойства и методы для отображения секции?

---

Помогите, пожалуйста! Я новичок в создании приложений и не очень-то и понимаю как необходимо правильно выстраивать архитектуру приложения.

Не хочется писать плохой код).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Моё мнение: объединять не стоит. Есть такой термин в программировании -- god object, когда у класса становится очень много ответственности. Вы сейчас движетесь по направлению к созданию такого класса. Вы уже сейчас вербализовали, что у вас есть три секции, что у них есть три разные ответственности ("начать тестирование", "отрисовка билетов").

И вот это стремление обьединить разное в единое -- путь к god object, который делает сразу всё. А ещё он не только кнопки отрисовывать будет, но и кофе варить и рассчитывать проценты по кредиту.

При этом фактически вы некоторые разные ответственности почему-то объединили с другими. Например, для меня очевидно, что ответственность "начать тестирование" и "настройки приложения" -- это совершенно разные вещи, но вы их мысленно объдиняете в "секция один". Нумерация -- вообще плохой советчик в этом вопросе. Если вы напишете public class Section1 вроде как всё логично, но если вы будете давать имя по смыслу, значению, ответственности -- то всегда насторожитесь, когда в названии класса вдруг появляется слово "And": КлассНачатьТестированиеИещёНастройки.

В вопросе разделения ответственностей вообще крайне редко приходится что-то объединять, как раз ООП подход рекомендует дробить классы как можно меньше.

Поэтому вам не нужен один мега-контроллер, вам нужно три (и даже более) независимых класса, которые будут отвечать только за свою часть.

Comment: Вы не правильно поняли мои намерения по разделению). Я не собирался называть классы **Section1** и т.п. Настройки и кнопка "Начать тестирование" у меня тоже почленно разделенные. Представленный код сильно был утрирован, чтобы дать общее представление о том, за что какая *визуальная* секция отвечает. Мне нужно было просто мнение опытных людей, о делении функционала на классы. Спасибо за адекватный и понятный ответ!

Comment: @zodiak1 Я знаю, что вы не собирались именно так называть. Как говорят литераторы, не отождествляйте себя с "литературным героем", просто считайте что это был такой приём, показать как люди думают, делают и объяснить на наглядном примере, чем это плохо.